# Upper, but not downer

Tags: etymology, word-usage

I was thinking of bounds for functions yesterday and it occurred to me that a bound from above is an "upper bound" (not "higher"), whereas a bound from below is a "lower bound".

Is there any etymological reason why we say ***"upper bound"*** but not "downer bound", or ***"lower bound"*** but not "higher bound"?

Comment: As Brian suggests, "upper" and "lower" have long been regarded as opposites, as in "upper and lower bunks".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because "higher" is scalable (high, higher, highest).  So is "low" (low, lower, lowest").

"up" and "down" are not scalable.  The suffix "er" on "upper" and "downer" does not make them comparatives.  In the case of the drug slang "upper" and "downer", it's an agentive suffix.  Something that brings you up or brings you down.

"Upper" as an adjective means **above** or **on top**.  "Lower" as an adjective means **below** or **on the bottom**. Consider bunk beds. There is a *lower bunk* (the one on the bottom) and an *upper bunk* (the one on the top). Likewise, the 1st and 2nd storeys of a house are the *lower floor* and the *upper floor* respectively.  And we have *lower* and *upper* teeth. In other words, when there are only two choices, rather than degrees of "upness" or "downness", the two choices are called *lower* and *upper*.

An aside:

There is not always symmetry in word usage. Our up-and-down words present other counterexamples: Consider *lower the bridge*. Now, if you put it up again, what did you do? You *raised* it—you didn't "higher" (or "upper") it. And back to drug slang:  you *get high* but you don't "get low"—you *come down*.

Anyway, I agree it's peculiar. But that's how English goes.  I'm not an etymologist, so I'll leave it at that.

Comment: Are you a relative of [Alfred](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alfred_Hitchcock)'s :)?

Answer (score 1):

The term ***[downer](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/downer)*** has been associateted more with a physical/phsychological state from the 60's when the term became popular, (see [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=downer&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdowner%3B%2Cc0)) probably from its earlier usage (Down:  sense of "depressed mentally" is attested from c. 1600.):

(n.) Slang

> - A depressant or sedative drug, such as a barbiturate or tranquilizer.
> - One that depresses, such as an experience or person.

(adj.)

> - Unable to stand because of disease or sometimes injury. Used of livestock.

(AHD)

***[Downer](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=downer):***

> - 1966 in sense of "barbiturate;" 1970 in sense of "depressing person;" agent noun from down (v.).

(Etymonline)

Comment: The drug references are about 100 years too late to have influenced the terms "upper bound" and "lower bound."  I suspect that the choice has something to do with the translations of the work of mathematicians Bolzano and Weierstrass, who wrote in German.  Alas, my German isn't good enough to check their work in the original.  Mostly because my German isn't good enough for anything.

Comment: @deadrat - I can't confirm or reject  what you are assuming,but  the fact that the term use  actually spiked up  from the 60's appear to support the idea of  a new trend in its usage.

Comment: @deadrat: well, "upper" is also used as the opposite of "lower" in place names, which seem unlikely to have all been influenced by German. For example: ["Upper India"](https://books.google.com/books?id=-UMOAAAAQAAJ&dq=%22upper%22&source=gbs_navlinks_s), ["Upper and Lower California"](https://books.google.com/books?id=NH4FAAAAQAAJ&dq=%22upper%22&source=gbs_navlinks_s), ["Upper and Lower Egypt"](https://books.google.com/books?id=_EAGAAAAQAAJ&dq=%22upper%22&source=gbs_navlinks_s)

Comment: If by "the term," you mean *downer*, then you're surely correct.  But the question is why *downer bound* isn't the opposite of *upper bound* when *down* is the opposite of *up*.  And that decision was made long before *Valley of the Dolls*.

Comment: @deadrat - downer is not the opposite of upper (unlike down vs up) for the reasons I mentioned IMO.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not following you.  In drug slang, the opposite of a downer (barbiturate) is indeed an upper (amphetamine).  The slang term downer isn't old enough to have influenced the choice of "lower bound" in function theory.  What am I missing?

Comment: @deadrat German https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beschr%C3%A4nktheit#.C3.9Cbertragung_auf_Funktionen.2C_auf_deren_Wertevorrat_eine_Abstandsfunktion_definiert_ist and French http://homeomath2.imingo.net/foncborn.htm terms. I am afraid they do not contribute much, although I agree that in this case the English terminology must be a translation.

Answer (score 0):

The ending *-er* is generally applied to adjectives. And *down* is not an adjective.

You might say "*Up* isn't an adjective either!", but apparently *up* was actually used as an adjective at one point. The OED entry for the adjective *upper* says

> Comparative of *up* adj., and signifying ‘higher’, ‘over’, ‘loftier’, ‘top’ (in contrast to *lower, nether, under*).

That said, the linked OED entry for *up* as an adjective doesn't seem to have many example quotations, so I'm not sure exactly what went on with the word *upper.*

In some cases, *higher* is in fact used as the opposite of *lower,* as in "higher and lower faculties" or apparently "[Higher and lower orders](https://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2010/02/a-class-act.html)".